# Open a same fragment with different information on a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have this "help section" in my application, which consists of a ListView with different items. I'm trying to open the same fragment when I click on each item of the ListView, but every time It opens, it should display different information.

I tried to use an intent and use getExtra when I open the fragment, but I was not successful. I'm a bit lost here, any help will be appreciated.

Here's my "help activity" code:

```
ListView list_main;
//Itens do LV
ListView list;
// ListView items
String[] item = {"   Como começar?", "   Como adcionar uma carona?", "    Como remover uma carona?",
        "   Como faço para pegar uma carona com alguém?", "   Minhas informações estão seguras?", "   Como editar meu perfil?",
        "   Tive um problema com uma carona, o que fazer?", "   Como trocar minha senha?", "   Preciso dividir o valor da carona?",
        "Recomendações aos usuários", "Entre em contato"
};
// ListView images
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.information, R.drawable.plus, R.drawable.removecloud, R.drawable.network,
        R.drawable.lock, R.drawable.user, R.drawable.siren, R.drawable.lock, R.drawable.piggy,
        R.drawable.recomenda, R.drawable.mail};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help_interno);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dúvidas Frequentes");

    HelpList adapter = new HelpList(HelpInterno.this,item,imageId); // Custom adapter
    list_main = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_main);
    list_main.setAdapter(adapter);

    list_main.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // What to do ?

        }
    })
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: You can just create separate adapters for different data you want to display and set adapters based on `position` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) how to pass data to a new fragment; in you scenario you can do like below
Put this code in your fragment class

```
public static HelpDetailFragment getStartFragment(String item, int imageId) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(EXTRA_ITEM, imageId);
        arguments.putString(EXTRA_IMAGE_ID, imageId);
        HelpDetailFragment fragment = new HelpDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, container, false);

        Bundle extras = getArguments();
        if (extras != null) {
            String item = extras.getString(EXTRA_ITEM);
            int imageid = extras.getInt(EXTRA_IMAGE_ID);
        }

        ....

        return rootView;
    }
```

Then navigate to the fragment when clicking the list item

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(/*your view detail id*/, HelpFragment.getStartFragment(item[position], imageId[position]))
                        .addToBackStack("help")
                        .commit();
}
```

Read about fragment navigation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace)

Answer (score 1):

try to do like this:

```
//make an instance for your fragment inside your fragment
public static your_fragment_name newInstance(String var1, String var2, int var3) {
    your_fragment_name fragment = new your_fragment_name();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(first_key, var1);
    args.putString(second_key, var2);
    args.putInt(third_key, var3);
    your_fragment_name.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

//get variables inside your fragment in this way
private getExtras(){
    String var1 = getArguments().getString(first_key);
    String var2 = getArguments().getString(second_key);
    int var2 = getArguments().getInt(third_key);
}

//call your fragment in this way
your_fragment_name fragment = your_fragment_name.newInstance(var1, var2, var3);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                      .replace(/*your view detail id*/,fragment).commit();
```